# Comparing against null in a tuple in Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

How can I check for nulls in the following query? Maintenance is not an issue. The query is being run automatically to check that database changes were made.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MSG_TYP_LKUP
  WHERE ((MSG_TYP,NM,SUB_TYP,DIRECT,FORMAT) IN
            (
                    ('setr.005','Cancel to Fund',NULL,'OUT','SWIFT-XML'),
                    ('setr.011','Cancel to Fund',NULL,'OUT','SWIFT-XML'),
                    ('setr.013','Order to Fund',NULL,'OUT','SWIFT-XML'),
                    ('setr.014','Cancel to Fund',NULL,'OUT','SWIFT-XML'),
                    ('setr.016','Order Received','RECE','OUT','SWIFT-XML'),
                    ('setr.016','Order Acknowledgement','STNP','OUT','SWIFT-XML')
            )
     );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method might be to insert a new value for `NULL`.  Something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM MSG_TYP_LKUP
WHERE ((MSG_TYP, NM, COALESCE(SUB_TYP, '<NULL>'), DIRECT, FORMAT) IN
            (
                    ('setr.005','Cancel to Fund', '<NULL>','OUT','SWIFT-XML'),
                    ('setr.011','Cancel to Fund', '<NULL>','OUT','SWIFT-XML'),
                    ('setr.013','Order to Fund', '<NULL>','OUT','SWIFT-XML'),
                    ('setr.014','Cancel to Fund', '<NULL>','OUT','SWIFT-XML'),
                    ('setr.016','Order Received','RECE','OUT','SWIFT-XML'),
                    ('setr.016','Order Acknowledgement','STNP','OUT','SWIFT-XML')
            )
     );
```

I'm not thrilled with this approach.  But Oracle doesn't have a `NULL`-safe comparison operator so this is probably the simplest method.

Comment: That's perfect. It'll be only run once so I can check for the replacement value beforehand anyway. Cheers for that.

Comment: Is there any database that has a NULL safe comparator that can be used with an `IN` condition?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . Not that I know of.  But I was thinking of switching to some other structure -- particularly a `JOIN` -- but the lack of `NULL`-safe operator would just complicate that.

Answer (score 1):

The safest way is to handle `NULL` explicitly. The code is longer, but execution is likely faster, and you are not introducing other problems. (For example, if you use a placeholder value for `NULL`, you must be 100% sure it's not a valid value in the data.)

Something like

```
WHERE (MSG_TYP,NM,SUB_TYP,DIRECT,FORMAT) IN
            (
                    ('setr.016','Order Received','RECE','OUT','SWIFT-XML'),
                    ('setr.016','Order Acknowledgement','STNP','OUT','SWIFT-XML')
            )
OR SUB_TYP IS NULL AND (MSG_TYP,NM,DIRECT,FORMAT) IN
            (
                    ('setr.005','Cancel to Fund','OUT','SWIFT-XML'),
                    ('setr.011','Cancel to Fund','OUT','SWIFT-XML'),
                    ('setr.013','Order to Fund','OUT','SWIFT-XML'),
                    ('setr.014','Cancel to Fund','OUT','SWIFT-XML')
            )
```

Moreover, you should probably factor out the last two columns, because they are required to have constant values in all tests. Oracle could use that to advantage (to filter out many rows very quickly, based on those columns), but I don't think the optimizer is smart enough to look for such shortcuts.

**EDIT** I was curious so I just ran a small test. At least in an uncomplicated query (very similar to the OP's) and Oracle 12.2.0.1, the optimizer **is** smart enough to factor out columns that are required to have a constant value over all comparison tuples in the `IN` list.